# How can I change the background behind the camera cutout and the app switcher?

Tags: android

As you can see on the picture, the camera area and the app switcher are not the right color.

I have code to hide and show the toolbar whenever the user touches the video to see the controls. I also have code that sets the `statusBarColor` to `black`. I've done some testing and `statusBarColor` only affects the notification bar, not the camera area or the app switcher.

My code to show the toolbars when the user touches the video looks like this:

```
    val mDecorView = window.decorView
    mDecorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
    
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true);
    val windowInsetsController =
        ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(window.decorView) ?: null
    windowInsetsController?.systemBarsBehavior =
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    windowInsetsController?.show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

I would prefer to solve this issue programmatically if possible.

What am I missing?

Edit: I would like to add that this is only an issue when I'm showing the controls and toolbar. When the controls are hidden my video stretches all the way under the camera without issues.

Edit: I should add that this is an issue on landscape mainly. On portrait on some phones I can see white on the app switcher but not on the cutout. I think I know how to fix the app switcher so the cutout is the main issue.

Edit: I think I've figured it out. `windowBackground` controls the cutout while in landscape. `navigationBarColor` controls the app switcher. I'm going to try to put it all in my code before answering the question.

[image]

Comment: "this is only an issue when I'm showing the controls and toolbar. When the controls are hidden my video stretches all the way under the camera without issues." So, the issue appears when you show the controls. Do you have special code that you'd show us when you show the controls?

Comment: Yeah, that is the code I pasted there. Basically I let ExoPlayer control the showing of controls and on the `setControllerVisibilityListener` I call the code I put in my post. I guess maybe my issue is because I'm setting `setDecorFitsSystemWindows` but if I don't do that then my toolbar ends up overlapping the notification bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this solves my issue. Put this code on `onCreate`.

```
    window.navigationBarColor = Color.BLACK
    window.decorView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```